# what should be the Prediction or Target variable for Suicide data in India

Tags: classification, random-forest, decision-trees

I am very new to machine learning.I am studying Suicide data in India from kaggle dataset.
https://www.kaggle.com/rajanand/suicides-in-india/kernels
But I am unable to understand ***what should be the target variable for prediction or classification***.
My immediate thought is that a socially important goal of such studies is a prevention of future suicides.For ex:
a number of suicides going to happen next year among students of a given high school. If a prediction value is high, then preventive measures need to be taken.
But I am unable to start which ML algorithm should i use or how to approach.I have completed data analysis.
Please help.